# Start Activity without bringing Application to front

Tags: android, service, android-context

I am working on a lock screen replacement for my media player, and I am having trouble with one aspect.

The lock screen itself is a new activity that is launched by my media service whenever the screen turns off.  The problem is that the Activity uses the applications context to launch, which causes it to bring the app to the front after the user unlocks.

I have tried using the services Context to start the activity, but I believe this does not work because the service itself is linked to the application.

Below is the code in the service that launches the activity:

```
Intent mLock = new Intent(context, LockScreen.class); 
mLock.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(mLock);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can launch this activity and keep my app in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching I was able to get the results I desired by adding a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`.  This allows the lock activity to start and end without bringing the parent application to the front.

I will continue to test this solution and post any drawbacks I find.  If anyone else would like to chime in on this feel free...I know this flag has drawn criticism in the past.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Josh, I know it's a bit of an old post...but do you mind sharing the final code that got you working? Did you start your activity without app context? Or was it FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Answer (score 3):

In the manifest set the task affinity of the lock screen.  That should sort you out without using FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.

Comment: While this works in some cases (user pushes Home button), it fails in other areas.  I have a method that calls finish(); to the activity, but this still pulls my main application to the front.  I applied by adding android:taskAffinity="" to the activity in the manifest.

Comment: Check that!  I added the callout to the wrong activity.  Can you explain why this is a better solution than using the flag?

Comment: Only because the SDK docs advise against FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.  I'd be nervous of using it in case there are other consequences.

Comment: If using affinity, you will see one more of our app in recent apps. But it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit unclear about your question. But I hope I got it right.

In case you want to activate the lock activity and when it is unlocked you don't want to see the activity(say activity X) that was running before the lock activity was called, then close this activity(X) before calling the lock activity.

If you want X to run even when the lock activity is active, but closed when it is unlocked, then use flags. Set a flag once it is unlocked and allow X to periodically check for this flag status.

Hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  What I would like to do is to keep whatever activity was on top when the screen powers off on top after unlocking.  Whether this is my media player or another app.  Right now the unlock activity always pulls my app to the top when the Lock activity starts

Comment: In case you haven't solved it, post some code. May be that can help!

Comment: I have not solved using your solution, but that is not to say it wouldn't work.  I would rather find a way to start the activity without using my applications context if possible.